# OpenID Connect consumer in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, openid, single-sign-on, lightopenid

I'm starting a project where people will log into somebody else's OpenID provider and my CRM vendor's membership system (people will log into the third party so they can change their preferences etc).  I'll therefore be a 'consumer'.

I mostly build in PHP and LightOpenID seems like a good choice for me to write my middleware script -- https://gitorious.org/lightopenid -- but now that OpenID Connect is the emerging new standard, and LightOpenID doesn't do OpenID Connect (and the maintainer seems pretty ambivalent about integrating it), is there anything comparable?

I really want to avoid using a database at all for the system I'm building, and I'm not interested in integrating the entire Zend Framework stuff.